# The meaning of the French idiom "La famille Bloggs"

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, france

What's the meaning of the French idiom "La famille Bloggs"?
In the dictionary it's translated as "the Bloggs family" but really I still can't get it... I only know that expression "Joe Bloggs" which means an average or ordinary man & everyone know "blog" for sure which is the website or to have or write a blog soOooo please help me...
Thanks

Comment: I searched for "la famille Bloggs" or even "la famille Blogs" and found nothing relevant. Where did you pick this one? Also this is good practice to give a link to the stuff you are refering to because not everybody evolve in the same scene.

Comment: I'm a native french, and I never hear such an expression... where did you encountered it?

Comment: In oxford dictionary for essential vocabulary in the relationships part....La famille, family (La famille Bloggs,  the Bloggs family) : that's what's written ‍♀️

Comment: And I searched too everywhere but also found nothing...that's why I am asking here  & I don't have a link cause it's Oxford dictionary from the store

Comment: What don't you get in “The Bloggs family”? That's the name of a (virtual) family.

Comment: I don't know  it can be 

Comment: I think you're right 

Answer (score 3):

> In oxford dictionary for essential vocabulary in the relationships
> part... *La famille*, family (*La famille Bloggs*, the Bloggs family) :
> that's what's written ‍♀️ – [Zuko](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44888/the-meaning-of-the-french-idiom-la-famille-bloggs#comment91464_44888)

The [chiefly British](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Joe_Bloggs) name [*Bloggs*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Joe%20Bloggs) is [used here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44888/the-meaning-of-the-french-idiom-la-famille-bloggs#comment91466_44888) as a [**placeholder name**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name) (like a type of [*pantonyme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantonymie)) to help you phrase a *family name* with the name *family*. It means *la famille [Nom de famille]*, *the [Family name] family*, or *la famille X*, *the X family* where [*X*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/x) is a family name. For instance : « La famille *Tremblay* [the Tremblay family] est très [nombreuse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nombreuse) [i.e. very big] ».

Generally, the British [*Joe Bloggs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Joe_Bloggs) is the same average *Joe* as [*Joe Blow*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Joe_Blow#English) and some cousin to the anonymous [*John*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/John_Doe#English)/[*Jane*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jane_Doe#English) *Doe*, some of which have travelled [up north](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jos_Bleau) etc.

In French you will have French types of names whether it's [*Jean Dupont*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Joe_Bloggs#Translations), *Tartempion* or [related](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tartempion#Synonymes), [*Monsieur Tout-le-monde*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Monsieur_Tout-le-Monde), or [some](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantonymie#Personnes) [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terms_related_to_an_average_person) but using *X* is arguably better and more neutral if you want to avoid any dismissive tone and actually don't mean *average* but rather *any* of a specific type, as is the case here with your Oxford dictionary entry.

---

This is not about an idiom but rather *Bloggs* is just a British English placeholder (family) name (from the name *Joe Bloggs*) for ***whatever*** family name.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Bloggs has nothing to do with blogs, the web sites you were refering to in your answer. I found this on Wikipedia, about Joe Bloggs origin:
"The name Bloggs is believed to have been derived from the East Anglian region of Britain, Norfolk or Suffolk, deriving from bloc, a bloke. In the UK, a "bloke" represents the average man on the street."
(Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Bloggs)

So "The Bloggs family" would refer to an average family.
I would propose a French adaptation, but it is dependent upon the context.
You could use "une famille lambda".

"lambda" is appended to any word you want to mean you take a typical ordinary normal one and use it in the latter explanation. This is borrowed from mathematics language and just adds a reference to something. "une famille moyenne" works too.

Another possibility, closer to the Joe Bloggs use, would be:
"La famille Test"
Because here everybody will understand this family is actually a function.

---

Wait. I just realized I took it the wrong way. Are you sure it is French in origin? Because in my opinion this is an ENGLISH idiom, not a French one.